# Select all child elements of parent of same class - CSS / Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to remove the left and right padding on all children .container classes after the top level parent .container even if there is other sub-parent div's in between.

In the example below I would like .container within .class2 and .class4 to have the following css:

```
padding-left: 0;
padding-right: 0;
```

But the first .container to have the left and right padding set by bootstrap.

I guess I could hack this and do something like:

```
.container {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.container:first-child {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

For Example:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="class1">
    <div class="class2>
      <div class="container">
      </div><!-- /container -->
    </div><!-- /class2 -->
  </div><!-- /class1 -->
  <div class="class3">
    <div class="class4>
      <div class="container">
      </div><!-- /container -->
    </div><!-- /class4 -->
  </div><!-- /class3 -->
</div><!-- /container (TOP LEVEL PARENT) -->
```

Comment: why not give an `id` for the top level parent container? it would be much easier to solve your problem.

Comment: Is .container:first-of-type what you are looking for?